# Is a struct with a single char array member guaranteed to have a predictable size?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider the following struct:

```
struct alignas(8) Foo {
    char data[8];
};
```

**Is it guaranteed by the Standard that `sizeof(Foo) == 8`?**

From a layman's point of view, it should be true, because 8 `char`s don't need any padding to have an alignment of 8.
And it seems to be true in practice on GCC, Clang, and MSVC ([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/exTE83E67)).

However, padding and alignment is a tricky business, and I couldn't find any information that strictly forbids implementations from adding extraneous padding - i.e. `sizeof(Foo) == 16` might be possible too?

I've found the following so far:

- `sizeof(char[8]) == 8` is guaranteed ([see here](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#2)), thus `sizeof(Foo) >= 8)`
- `Foo` does not have leading padding, since it is a standard layout type ([see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout))
- At least one more knowledgeable person - the author of `std::bit_cast` - apparently believes there is no padding - [see this article](https://gist.github.com/shafik/a956a17d00024b32b35634eeba1eb49e)

<sub>(Interestingly, if this fact is untrue, it would seem to imply that structs can have arbitrarily large size, which is a bit strange.)</sub>

Comment: The link you provide about `std::bit_cast` is not definitive - it is about one particular implementation that relies on an *assumption* of no padding, and triggers diagnostics if that assumption is not true.      In any event, the size of most types (other than `char` types and some of the fixed size types) is implementation-defined - which means the standard doesn't explicitly *prevent* additional padding in your case.    That said, there wouldn't be too many implementations that would introduce additional padding, since there is little/no benefit to justify it.

Comment: @Peter I know it's not definitive, but from my interpretation the author does believe the struct has no padding. They mention the sizeof restriction and then say "After discussing this with the JF Bastien the proposal's author as well as the author of the reference implementation, one way around this restriction ...".
My thoughts were that if no compiler adds padding, and at least 1 "expert" thinks there is no padding, then maybe it's at least the case that the Standard is ambiguous. However I do realise the likely reality that it's just not specified.

Comment: *"it would seem to imply that structs can have arbitrarily large size, which is a bit strange."* -- on the other hand, why should the standard impose a limitation that compiler writers are likely to impose on themselves? Who wants a compiler that gratuitously makes structs arbitrarily large? So I would argue for "not strange", while accepting that others may have different opinions. Unless there is a (non-contrived) usecase for ensuring that the size in this case is exactly 8?

Comment: @JaMiT There are definitely non-contrived use cases for having guarantees about struct sizes and padding. Serialisation and register mapping in embedded platforms immediately come to mind. In fact, this issue came up as a result of me working on some real world serialisation code. I argue that if every compiler gives such guarantees, it may as well be guaranteed by the standard for the purposes of portability (but it seems like *not* every compiler gives these guarantees).

Comment: @MCΔT: Why would those guarantees need to be in the standard itself? You're doing embedded programming; that basically requires that you have an intimate understanding of how your compiler will interact with certain things on the platform. Your code isn't meant to be portable.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok sure, but my argument still applies for portable serialisation (which, like I said, it literally the reason my question came up, so please don't try to tell me it's a complete non-issue).

Comment: @MCΔT: Binary copying of object data cannot be portable, since that would require all implementations to store all object data in the exact same way. It can be portable within a family of implementations, but it is not a goal of the standard to ensure that binary data copied from one implementation can be read by another.

Comment: @NicolBolas true, but you can definitely get some of the way there thanks to guarantees such as standardised two's complement integers, in C++20. I imagine most compilers used two's complement anyway, but standardisation is just a nice thing to have. In a similar vein, I think it'd be nice to have some guarantees about struct padding/size, if many compilers effectively provide such guarantees anyway.

Comment: @MCΔT: I don't see (much) point in standardizing the padding of a struct when we don't have standardized *sizes* for the types *within* that struct. Also, the guarantees about struct layout are defined by a platform's ABI; compilers merely conform to that. C++ is not going to have a standard ABI.

Answer (score 6):

Implementations are free to add as much padding as they want. The size of a type is constrained to at minimum the size of its contents, but that's all the standard requires.

I can't really point to something that isn't there, so I can't link to the part of the standard that doesn't impose a limitation.

Broadly speaking, implementations won't do weird things to the sizes of types. And ABI requirements can limit implementations. But as far as the standard itself is concerned, there is no such requirement.

Comment: So, *strictly speaking*, no **guarantee** of a predictable size.  Unlikely, for any familiar platform.  But for unusual platforms, like the DS9K ABI that imposes some "must be aligned on every 23 bytes" requirement for structs, then there may be 15 padding bytes.

Comment: @Eljay in that case though, isn't that what C++'s concept of alignment is for? I.e. if I specify alignas(8) but the platform requires 23-byte alignment, the code is ill-formed, right?. Is there some reason that padding would be added other than for alignment?

Comment: *if I specify alignas(8) but the platform requires 23-byte alignment, the code is ill-formed, right?*  No, that's not how **alignas** works; it's the largest of the set of all alignment constraints.  The example only has one member, but if there was another member and it had its only alignment constraints, there could be intra-struct padding between members.

Comment: @Eljay Perhaps we are referring to different things, but I see this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas. "If the strictest (largest) alignas on a declaration is weaker than the alignment it would have without any alignas specifiers ... the program is ill-formed". MSVC and GCC don't seem to respect it, but Clang does.

Comment: @MCΔT: The standard [explicitly forbids non-power-of-two alignments](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.align#4.sentence-3). And yes, it also [forbids specifying an alignment that is less than the natural alignment of the type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.align#5.sentence-1).